# Bootstrap 3 dropdown arrows are not displayed correctly on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have this weird problem with the standard caret of Bootstrap: on Chrome's developer device tools it is displayed correctly, but when I view the same page on mobile the arrows is rendered as a rectangle. And I can't figure out why? Can anybody help, please?

[image: The icon is not correctly displayed]

[Test Page, view it with mobile to see the error](http://www.lyra.net/en/songs/pink-floyd/wish-you-were-here/wish-you-were-here.php)

(this question is different from the others I checked because the problem is generally on mobiles)

Comment: I didn't check on mobile but maybe the glyphicons file hasn't been downloaded by the browser yet.

Comment: No, the page is fully loaded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding this to my css:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .caret{
    border-top: 4px solid;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't know how you came up with this solution (border-top? Incredible!) but thanks, it really works :)